# ndb gae repeated KeyPropery and transactions

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I run into some problems trying to create entities using this structure:

```
class MainEnt(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    choices = ndb.KeyProperty(repated=True)

    @classmethod
    @ndb.transactional
    def create(cls, name, choices):
        #Here comes my problem!

class Choice(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

So here I have a main entity that haves a list of some choices.
To create the main entity I need to use a transaction to consistently create the main entity and the choices entities. If some operation fail I want all to fail.

The problem is that to run inside a transaction all need to be in the same entity group but I can't do that because I don't know the key of the main entity to assign it as the parent argument to each choice. I can't use allocate_ids inside a transaction so this option doesn't work.

I don't want to use Cross-Group transactions, and also don't want to save the main entity two times.

Also I was considering using queries to fetch the choices and don't use the repeated property, but as long as I will usually only have 2-3 choices per MainEnt, using queries is a waste of resources.

What can I do?

Comment: Are you trying to create all the Choice entities at the same time and store their keys in the choices property ?  Surely all MainEnt's would refer to the shared set of Choice entities. I suggest you show what code you are running inside your `create` factory so we can see what you are really up to.

Comment: If instances of the choice entity are owned by MainEnt then you could just create them as children and drop the repeated KeyProperty.

Comment: The code inside create is what i'm looking for... Maybe something like: create the MainEnt and put it, then create the choices and put them, and then modify choices property in MainEnt with the keys of the Choices created later. Here as you see. I put 2 times MainEnt. I'm looking for a formula to do this writting to the datastore only 2 times.

Comment: So are instances of choices shared with all MainEnt instances or exclusive to a single instance of MainEnt?

Comment: No, Choices are not shared. Each one is unique to its MainEnt.

Comment: The only purpose of having the repeated choices property is to avoid using a query to fetch the Choices, and instead do a get_multi on the keys. Because getting the Choices is very very common.

Comment: Why not store choices as a repeated StructuredProperty ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to fetch all Choices every time then just use a repeated StructuredProperty

```
class Choice(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

class MainEnt(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    choices = ndb.StructuredProperty(Choice,repeated=True)

    def create(cls, name, choices):
       m = cls.MainEnt(name=name)
       m.choices = [Choice(name=name) for name in choices]
       m.put()
```

Comment: ok, this question may not be part of this, but every time I access the properties of a Choice I'm going to perform a get to the datastore?

Comment: Huh ?  Using a StructuredProperty means when you fetch a MainEnt you already have all the choices (they are stored in the entity not seperately), you can't get to them without fetching the MainEnt.

Comment: I suggest you read the docs on Structured Properties https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured

Comment: this could be the answer although it completely changes my model structure.  thanks!

Comment: What you were trying to do is quite inefficent , do you have a use case out weighing the expense.

Comment: Tim, just another question... What if Choice has also other Entities that belong to them? I mean, suppose Choice has 0 or more "Answers" that are unique to each Choice. How can I model that? Going the same approach I intended to later, has the same problem. I check the docs for Structured Property and says only one level can be repeated. THANKS

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand what you are trying to do.  One option is to collect the Answers in a dictionary or list and then store that in a BlobProperty in the Choice instance.